# How to configure Fiddler to listen to localhost?

Tags: localhost, fiddler

I want to monitor HTTP traffic between a process on my local machine and another (server) process, also running on my local machine.

How can I configure Fiddler to listen to traffic to and from `localhost`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Fiddler to stop ignoring traffic to localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214308/how-do-i-get-fiddler-to-stop-ignoring-traffic-to-localhost)

Answer (score 151):

By simply adding fiddler to the url

```
http://localhost.fiddler:8081/
```

Traffic is routed through fiddler and therefore being displayed on fiddler.

Comment: Works in .net without having to set proxy in the HttpClientHandler!

Comment: This method works will with Visual Studio's test webserver according to Telerik's documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic

Comment: Even this is overkill. All you have to do is use the computer's IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: I had also to add header `host:localhost.fiddler` , otherwise localhost traffic will not routed to proxy.

Answer (score 62):

Add a dot `.` after the `localhost`.

For example if you had **http://localhost:24448/HomePage.aspx**

Change it to **http://localhost.:24448/HomePage.aspx**

Internet Explorer is bypassing the proxy server for "localhost". With the dot, the "localhost" check in the domain name fails.

Comment: Technically it's not Internet Explorer bypassing the proxy, it is DNS itself. `localhost` in DNS always resolves without using a proxy. More info on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost)

Comment: As a side tip, if you want to also capture traffic to web services within .net, set the web service proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888 before calling the ws.

Answer (score 21):

.NET and Internet Explorer don't send requests for localhost through any proxies, so they don't come up on Fiddler.

Many alternatives are available

Use your machine name instead of localhost.
Using Firefox (with the fiddler add-on installed) to make the request.
Use http://ipv4.fiddler instead of localhost.

For more info http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Comment: I believe with IE 9 RC, Fiddler can now capture the localhost requests

Comment: I push the URL changed for the [help](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost) see above

Answer (score 9):

try putting your machine name/IP address instead of 'localhost' into URL.
Works for me...

Answer (score 6):

Rather than configure the application server and client to use another domain, you may want to configure the client application to use a proxy.  Fiddler also creates a proxy you can use, logging all traffic.  Rick Strahl blogged about using this in .NET Apps, I am always misplacing this blog post, so let me link it here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Mar/14/Debugging-Http-or-Web-Services-Calls-from-ASPNET-with-Fiddler.

To be brief, the app.config change is:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy  proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />      
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Instead if you machine is named "myMachine", point your browser to http://mymachine instead of http://localhost

Comment: tried even that but can't listen to it when url rewriting is enabled, however when url redirecting is enabled it shows it.

Answer (score 2):

And I just found out that on vista 'localhost.' will not work. In this case use '127.0.0.1.' (loopback address with a dot appended to it).

Answer (score 2):

tools => fiddler options => connections there is a textarea with stuff to jump, delete LH from there

Comment: you can't delete loopback from there.  If you do, it merely reappears automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `localhost` by `lvh.me` in your URL

For example if you had **http://localhost:24448/HomePage.aspx**

Change it to **http://lvh.me:24448/HomePage.aspx**

Answer (score 1):

Replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 If it doesn't work change the run configuration to support your ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Fiddler v4.4.7.1. I needed to use localhost:8888 or machinename:8888 when using the Composer tab. Look at the Help/About Fiddler menu option, where it says, "Running on:".  Mine shows machinename:8888 there.

Answer (score 0):

The Light,

You can configure the process acting as the client to use fiddler as a proxy.

Fiddler sets itself up as a proxy conveniently on 127.0.0.1:8888, and by default overrides the system settings under Internet Options in the Control Panel (if you've configured any) such that all traffic from the common protocols (http, https, and ftp) goes to 127.0.0.1:8888 before leaving your machine.

Now these protocols are often from common processes such as browsers, and so are easily picked up by fiddler. However, in your case, the process initiating the requests is probably not a browser, but one for a programming language like php.exe, or java.exe, or whatever language you are using.

If, say, you're using php, you can leverage curl. Ensure that the curl module is enabled, and then right before your code that invokes the request, include:

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');**

Hope this helps. You can also always lookup stuff like so from the fiddler documentation for a basis for you to build upon e.g. http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigurePHPcURL

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FireFox, Fiddler's add-on will automatically configure it to not ignore localhost when capturing traffic. If traffic from localhost is still (or suddenly) not appearing, try disabling and re-enabling traffic capture from Fiddler to goad the add-on into fixing the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Just grab your computer's IP address with IPconfig at the command prompt. Then, hit the service using the IP address rather than localhost. You don't need to do anything to Fiddler to make this work, it will just work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Firefox, which does not go through Internet Options like IE, Chrome, and Edge do, you can use `about:config` to modify preferences, find the preference `network.proxy.no_proxies_on` and remove `localhost` from it.

This was the default setting for Firefox Developer Edition 66.0b2 and worked with Fiddler 5.0.20182.28034.

(Other listed solutions do work, this solution allows you to not change the host you are navigating to.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to proxy settings in Firefox and choose "Use system proxy" but be sure to check if there is no exception for localhost in "no proxy for" field.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To complete answer of [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745274/3142139)

To allow .Net full Framework net4+ to pass via fiddler, i had to:

1. replace `localhost` with `localhost.fiddler`
2. Add a header to the request `host:localhost.fiddler` , otherwise localhost traffic will not pass to proxy.

**In net5+ application , localhost traffic pass to fiddler without any modification**

This is tested in `fiddler v5`