# WebClient error 417 when posting login

Tags: c#

I've been trying to use a WebClient to post data for a login form, however no matter what I do I keep getting back a 417 Expect error. I tried the "ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;" and it hasn't done a thing. I am beginning to suspect this may be an error in my code, but I can't tell what it is.

```
    public void initiateCredits(string user, string pass)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc2 = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string webData = wc2.DownloadString("http://localhost");
        Regex check = new Regex("(?<=You have)(.*)(?=credits)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        bool checkmatch = check.IsMatch(webData);
        if (checkmatch == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            DisableClickSounds();
            string url = "http://localhost";
            string pass_d = Base64.decode(pass);
            string postData = String.Format("username=" + user + "&password=" + pass_d);
            byte[] Post = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            byte[] response = wc.UploadValues(url, new NameValueCollection()
   {
       { "username", user },
       { "password", pass_d }
   });
            creditlogin = true;

            //string AdditionalHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //wb.Navigate(url, null, Post, AdditionalHeaders);
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can't seem to remove these headers, or why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what's going on on the wire. Is there an `Expect` header field in the response of the server? They are sometimes required for some kind of authentication.

Comment: But check out how to fiddle localhost, if using it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647105/how-to-configure-fiddler-to-listen-to-localhost

Comment: I have fiddler working, and yes it is still sending the Expect header no matter what I set "ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue" to.

Comment: And, just to be sure, the value of the header field is `100-continue`?

Comment: The response header I get is `HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed` and the Transport says `Expect: 100-continue`

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines to your application config file configuration section - in my case only this prevents from sending "Expect:" header:

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```