# Inspect signalR message with Fiddler among wpf apps

Tags: c#, wpf, websocket, signalr, fiddler

I searched and see there is a post "Inspect SignalR Message with Fiddler". But I tried everything it mentioned (click stream button, or remove web socket from transport), I am still not able to get any traffic message about signalR in fiddler. I have a wpf application as server, and another wpf application as client. The communication works, client calls server and server calls client, both work well. Is there anything else I could try and is that because my client is wpf application so I cannot see the traffic in fiddler?
I want to see the traffic like this in fiddler:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is this localhost only? Then you may need to change your url as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647105/how-to-configure-fiddler-to-listen-to-localhost

Comment: Hi yes, both the client and server are on my localhost. The only two places I have url are below: Server side code      _signalRHost = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8089/");   Client side code    new HubConnection("http://localhost:8089/");   I tried to change localhost to my computer name it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Some post said to monitor websocket traffic in fiddler, we need to click stream button in the toolbar. I also tried that, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: As explained in the so post I linked above - have you tried setting the url on the client to "http://localhost.fiddler:8089/". Also, are you able to see other traffic? Before SignalR opens the webSocket (if it does at all because there might be reasons why the client picks a different transport) it sends a couple of HTTP requests. Can you see these?

Comment: Hi I tried localhost.fiddler:8089 but still no luck. I think my may not use webSocket transport, because I have EnableJson = true in my web configuration. If it is not web socket, am I still supposed to see the requests? And I cannot see any http requests relates to signalR. I can see other http requests when I send requests to other hosts. The only local host thing I see is vshub.....