# How to include bypass URL's list in system proxy setting using fiddler c#

Tags: c#, fiddler

In fiddler we have a option in Tools -> Options -> Connections -> Bypass Fiddler for URL's that starts with, how to use this option in c#.

currently I'm trying RegistryKey object in c#, but every time when i run fiddler through c# windows application it is overriding it and replacing it with "<-loopback>;",

[image: In Fiddler Tool[![System Proxy Settings]
**Update:**

**is this the correct way:**

**source:** https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/BypassUpstreamProxy

```
void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession) {
            if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.com")) {
                oSession.bypassGateway = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Lookback IP address is 127.0.0.1.  So it looks like using a dash is using the CONSTANT in Fiddler.  So you need to use something like : 172.0.0.0;173.0.0.0.  It looks like the proxy include the port number.  It also looks like you need to use a different Proxy at top of form.  It is replace the bottom of form with -loopback because top of form contains 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer, is there any way I can include url's using fiddler for that IP 127.0.0.1, because my client is using 127.0.0.1:80 proxy, hence I cannot change that.

Comment: You can use IP address or name instead of loopback.  They are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'm not clear enough, do we have any property or method in fiddler c# to add these url's, because I have seen a option in Fiddler Tool to include these URL list, but I want to achieve this using c# code.

Comment: What is your connection method?  Are you using a TCP client or an HTTP request?  Have you tried localhost?

Comment: FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.AllowRemoteClients |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.ChainToUpstreamGateway |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.MonitorAllConnections |
                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.CaptureLocalhostTraffic);

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647105/how-to-configure-fiddler-to-listen-to-localhost