# Logging localhost HTTP requests from PHP in Fiddler

Tags: debugging, fiddler

I have a test website hosted on Apache on my local machine.  I have a php script that makes a call to a remote website.

I would like to capture this traffic in Fiddler, but I'm assuming that Apache is opening another port to perform that communication so Fiddler doesn't know about it.

How should I configure Fiddler to know about that communication?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Fiddler to stop ignoring traffic to localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214308/how-do-i-get-fiddler-to-stop-ignoring-traffic-to-localhost)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because this is a different issue.  localhost traffic is being captured, it is just the external calls from apache that are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture curl traffic use [the following line](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigurePHPcURL) before making any curl calls:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

This configures curl to use fiddler as a proxy for it's external traffic.