# Elasticsearch Fiddler No DNS

Tags: elasticsearch, fiddler

I'm trying to work with Elasticsearch and Fiddler. I'm having some trouble with No DNS. The Elasticsearch is running fine. When I try the localhost:9200 I get the No DNS response. Any suggestions? I'm rookie here, so I might miss something. Thank You. 
Regards

Comment: The used set-up is unclear by your description, especially how Fiddler is involved. You should edit your question and improve it.

Comment: Try appending a period to localhost, I.e. Http://localhost.:9200

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214308/how-do-i-get-fiddler-to-stop-ignoring-traffic-to-localhost