# How can I see the JSON being sent by Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using this in some c# code in an MVC application.

```
var request = client.PutAsJsonAsync(path, myobj).
```

It works fine - but how can I snoop on the JSON that is being sent to the web server (at path)?

Is there any way to do this with the debugger - or to output the JSON that is being sent back to the MVC application? Thx.

Comment: Create a class extending DelegatingHandler

Comment: Fiddler can help you. Or you can use something like Postman as client for your API

Comment: Fiddler helps if I'm calling get from the browser, or composing requests manually - but I have C# code calling a web service directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Use proxy to debug traffic
- Use API testing tool
- Modify your code to log requests/responses

First option - proxy. Take a look on [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It shows you request/response data and allows to see https data too. As @Balazs noted, with Fiddler you can compose, capture, edit and send requests as well.

Second option - API testing tool. There are lot of them (SoapUI, RESTClient etc), but I suggest to take a look on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). It allows touching your API both manually and automatically via tests.

Last option is up to you. E.g. you can create [OWIN Middleware](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps), which will log request and/or response.

---

UPDATE: Seems like you want to log requests on client side instead of server side. So instead of OWIN Middleware you can create custom message handler:

```
public class LoggingHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
       HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // log request or its part here
        Logger.Trace(request.ToString());
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And pass it to `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler());
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/blah");
```

Comment: It is worth noting that one can compose and/or edit requests using Fiddler as well.

Comment: (obviously I can't use Fidler to watch C# code calling a web service directly - or if I can - how?)

Comment: @niico what do you mean by *raw* request? What do you mean by *watching c# code*? It can be any code - your c# or java application, some test tool like curl or browser. Fiddler will catch request. And it's not clear on which side you want to see raw request - some client application or webapi application?

Comment: raw request - I just want to see the JSON web api is generating and sending to the web service. I am calling the web service *from C# server side code*. I want to see what is being sent. Fidler isn't catching this code - (and I'm using http://127.0.0.1).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214308/how-do-i-get-fiddler-to-stop-ignoring-traffic-to-localhost

Comment: I am using machine name. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but I have a request going from 'server' C# code (running on my local machine) - to a web api web service (running on my local machine). I am not using a browser to call the service directly. Should fiddler be picking this up?

Comment: @niico yes, you can. If you run client service from different account, them just add defaultProxy setting to system.net in configuration file. Check also my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extending DelegatingHandler

Then ...

```
Protected Overrides Async Function SendAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

    LogRequest(request) ' this is where the request is

    ' Create and process response
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Nothing
    response = Await MyBase.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)

    LogResponse(response) ' here is the reponse

    Return response
End Function

 Private Function LogResponse(response As HttpResponseMessage) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim theJSON As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ExtractLoggingInfoFromResponse(response))

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

....then in Global.asax, register the handler with:
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(New YourClassNameHandler)